# Python for .NET import error

Tags: python, .net, clr, importerror, python.net

I am trying to use some functions from a dll 'XXX_CLR.dll' which contains a 'XXX_CLR' assembly. Here is my code:

```
import clr

print clr.FindAssembly('XXX_CLR')
print clr.AddReference('XXX_CLR')

import XXX_CLR
```

which gives me an ImportError:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\\XXX_CLR.dll
XXX_CLR, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\cygwin64\home\user\owncloud\Projects\Biotic\Spectrum\code\hamamatsu.py", line 6, in <module>
    import XXX_CLR
ImportError: No module named XXX_CLR
```

Comment: The problem may be that you are trying to mix cpython installed in cygwin with .NET framework installed in native Windows environment. What does `print clr.FindAssembly('XXX_CLR')` show? Did you add path to this DLL to sys.path?